# WebBrowser Control in a web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webbrowser-control

I tried to use the WebBrowser control in an ASP .NET application:

```
public BrowserForm()
        {
            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
   // code here
    }
```

But got error:

> '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2'
>   cannot be instantiated because the
>   current thread is not in a
>   single-threaded apartment

Then I did something like this:

```
     public BrowserForm()
        {
            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(StartThread);
            var t = new Thread(ts);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();

        }
        [STAThread]
        public void StartThread()
        {
            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        [STAThread]
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           //code here
        }
```

But still it's not working for me as desired...giving me weired errors like:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
>   from a call to a COM component

Any work around?? I'm not an expert of threading or COM but trying to convert a WindowApplication to WebApplication which takes a screenshot of a web page provided a URL. :(

Comment: Though you asked for a solution, but just thinking... one way to achieving the same to create an ActiveX control that would do the screen-shot job, and add it to your ASP.NET app...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this codeproject article [Using the WebBrowser Control in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebBrowser.aspx).

In that article go to the Technical Specifications section, and there you can see how he handled this STA thread issue.

> First of all, a WebBrowser control has
>   to be in a thread set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)), so I
>   need to create a thread and call the
>   SetApartmentState() method to set it
>   to ApartmentState.STA before starting
>   it.

Hope this helps

Cheer

Comment: How he handled this STA thread issue? I don't see this answer as useful. Can you please elaborate how he handled this issue, I cannot see it.
It is not good explanation to point only link to another page...

Answer (score 0):

You can set AspCompat="true" in the page's page directive and it will run in an STA. After you have done that your first example should work

Answer (score 0):

[WinInet is not supported for use in services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238425), which means any application that uses WinInet, such as IE's webbrowser control, isn't supported in services (e.g. asp.net services).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the webbrowser control in an asp.net based application?
It looks like you want to have a browser inside a browser.

Using it, you are limiting the audience to use IE (and Windows, I suppose).

Can't you use IFrame or Ajax or some other alternative?
Post your reasons & people might suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Asking "Why?" is counter productive in this case. Either give an answer or suggest a way to accomplish the task: "... trying to convert a WindowApplication to WebApplication which takes a screenshot of a web page provided a URL."

Comment: Why? Because I want to print an HTML page to a printer and you're supposed to use a WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to use WebBrowser control in my .Net page. Found this article which exactly answers your question.

[Capture Screenshot (Snapshot) Image of Website (Web Page) in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Windows-Forms-WebBrowser-control-in-ASPNet.aspx)